# Views as separator lines (or borders) are being cut if height is less than 1dp - React Native

Tags: javascript

I have a 3 titles on Text's components and a divider below each one as View's components. They have the following styles.

```
title: {
    ...PosText,
    color: Palette.TEXT_ON_LIGHT,
    paddingBottom: 9,
  },
  divider: {
    height: 0.5,
    backgroundColor: Palette.BACKGROUND_DIVIDERS,
    marginBottom: 1,
  },
```

I should see the title and a line divider beneath them but the first divider gets lost.

[image]

Comment: Don't put fraction of pixels elements, it's rendered inconsistently on different browsers. Use different browser/resize page and it should appear

Comment: This is React Native. I totally agree fractions are not helping, but isn´t any other way to draw lines which are less than 1dp?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a quick `SeparatingLine` component and set the `borderWidth` as you wish (add margins as needed).
I am using something like this in my project:

```
export default class SeparatingLine extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.separatingLine} />
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  separatingLine: {
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    borderColor: 'grey',
  },
});
```

Comment: Hey Gal! Unfortunately that makes the line also 1dp cause it´s adding the top and bottom border of 0.5. And pushing borderWidth to 0.25 doesn´t show anything.